# Migrating a single-user Google Workspace

Tags: migration, g-suite

I have 2 small free "legacy" GSuite / Google Workspace accounts.
I want to merge them into one (making domain2 an alias of domain1).

I see the tool to migrate the emails via IMAP. Some other things I'll be able to migrate manually. Others I understand will be lost (my google maps reviews for example).

My question is regarding the actual merging part. How do I make sure there is minimum downtime?
What is the process to link domain2 to domain1, knowing that it is currently attached to a workspace account already?

What about my google identity nathan@domain2 ?

Answer (score 0):

CubeBackup should help.  Take a look at https://www.cubebackup.com/docs/tutorials/transfer-gsuite-data-to-another-account/